# Fitting a table in 2 column paper format

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicol, white-space

I am having  a hard time trying to fit a table in my 2 column latex paper.

```
    \documentclass[nocrop]{bioinfo}

     \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
     \bibliographystyle{natbib.bst}
    \copyrightyear{2020} \pubyear{2020}
     \access{Advance Access Publication Date: Day Month Year}
    \appnotes{Manuscript Category}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[!b]
\centering
\processtable{Precision, Recall and Accuracy of graphs elucidated with BIC score, $Score_{LOPC}$ and $Score_{LASSO}$. Search method: greedy hill-climbing search \label{Tab:02}} {\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lllllll@{}}

\toprule Score & $\gamma$& Max parents & Precision  & Recall & SHD  & BAC\\\midrule

BIC             & -     & 3 & 0.4626 & 0.5212 & 135.52  & 0.7446 \\

$Score_{LOPC}$  & 0.6   & 3 & \textbf{0.5162} & 0.5242 & \textbf{120.89} & \textbf{0.7491} \\

$Score_{LASSO}$ & 0.6   & 3 & \textbf{0.5042} & 0.5328 & \textbf{123.9} & \textbf{0.7526} \\
\midrule
BIC         & -     & Inf & 0.1608 & \textbf{0.6954} & 504.77  & 0.7494 \\

$Score_{LOPC}$  & 0.6 & Inf & \textbf{0.2024} & 0.6733 & \textbf{379.93} & \textbf{0.7652} \\
$Score_{LASSO}$ & 0.6   & Inf & \textbf{0.1758} & 0.6929 & \textbf{456.13} & \textbf{0.7585} \\
\botrule
\end{tabularx}}{}
\end{table}


\begin{table}%[!ht]
\processtable{Total number and percentage of experimentally verified arcs found using BN structure learning with BIC, $Score_{LOPC}$ and $Score_{LASSO}$. Search Method: Greedy hill-climbing search \label{Tab:03}} {\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}p{2cm}p{0.5cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}@{}}  
\toprule Score & $\gamma$ & Total arcs & $\%$ of experimentally verified arcs & No. of experimentally verified arcs \\\midrule
BIC      & -    & 7742 & 19.32 & 1496 \\
$Score_{LOPC}$ & 0.0 & 1276 & 18.02 & 230  \\
$Score_{LOPC}$ & 0.2 & 1788 & 18.51 & 331 \\
\midrule
$Score_{LASSO}$ & 0.0 & 1355 & 20.22 & 274  \\
$Score_{LASSO}$ & 0.2 & 1374 & 20.08 & 376 \\
\botrule
\end{tabularx}}{}
\end{table}
```

It is hard to make a MWE because it happens what i compile the entire paper, not when i only have the tables in my work. The column next to the table goes blank[image]

Comment: It might be easier to align horizontally both tables.

Comment: @Bernard how do i do that?

Comment: You have the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle), used with `floatrow`. Do you need a caption?

Comment: These are two separate tables with separate captions

Comment: That's no problem  with floatrrow. If you do not need to have the side by side, you can use  `\InsertBoxC`, from the `insbox`  plain TeX macro package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the first table, I wouldn't use a `tabularx` environment as no line breaks within cells are needed; I'd use a `tabular*` environment instead. In the case of the second table, you're not using the `tabularx` environment properly as none of the columns are of type `X`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[nocrop]{bioinfo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,ragged2e,lipsum,microtype}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textrm{#1}} % how to display variable names
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\processtable{Precision, Recall and Accuracy of graphs elucidated with BIC score, $\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$ and $\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$. Search method: Greedy hill-climbing search.\label{Tab:02}}%
{\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{6}{c}}
\toprule 
Score & $\gamma$ & Max parents & Precision & Recall & SHD  & BAC\\
\midrule
BIC             & --     & 3 & 0.4626 & 0.5212 & 135.52  & 0.7446 \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$  & 0.6   & 3 & \textbf{0.5162} & 0.5242 & \textbf{120.89} & \textbf{0.7491} \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$ & 0.6   & 3 & \textbf{0.5042} & 0.5328 & \textbf{123.9\phantom{0}} & \textbf{0.7526} \\
\midrule
BIC         & --     & Inf & 0.1608 & \textbf{0.6954} & 504.77  & 0.7494 \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$  & 0.6 & Inf & \textbf{0.2024} & 0.6733 & \textbf{379.93} & \textbf{0.7652} \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$ & 0.6   & Inf & \textbf{0.1758} & 0.6929 & \textbf{456.13} & \textbf{0.7585} \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\processtable{Total number and percentage of experimentally verified arcs found using BN structure learning with BIC, $\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$ and $\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$. Search method: Greedy hill-climbing search.\label{Tab:03}}% 
{\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lccCC@{}}  
\toprule 
Score & $\gamma$ & Total arcs & $\%$ of experimentally verified arcs & No. of experimentally verified arcs \\
\midrule
BIC      & --    & 7742 & 19.32 & 1496 \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$ & 0.0 & 1276 & 18.02 & 230 \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LOPC}}$ & 0.2 & 1788 & 18.51 & 331 \\
\midrule
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$ & 0.0 & 1355 & 20.22 & 274 \\
$\vn{Score}_{\vn{LASSO}}$ & 0.2 & 1374 & 20.08 & 376 \\
\botrule
\end{tabularx}}{}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-10] % generate some filler text
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query. The amount of whitespace between the two floats and between the lower float and the text does seem to be quite excessive, doesn't it? The `bioinfo` document class provides the following definitions for the parameters `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep`, and `\intextsep`.

```
% Space between floats
\setlength\floatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
% Space between floats and text
\setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
% Space above and below an inline figure
\setlength\intextsep   {18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
```

Try inserting the following instructions in the preamble

```
\setlength\floatsep    {6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\textfloatsep{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\intextsep   {6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

and check if the result is more pleasing.

Comment: Thank you it work. Can you also suggest how to get rid of extra space under the tables

Comment: @HamdaBinteAjmal - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: You could put both tabulars and captions into one table.  It **is** curious that the next paragraph breaks after 2 lines.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - My apologies for the false impression created by the screenshot: The left-hand column actually continues on for many more lines. I'll post a new, hopefully less misleading, screenshot shortly. About placing both tabulars and their captions in a single `table` environment: I thought about that but didn't as the OP's write-up indicated to me that separate `table` environments should be employed. However, I may have been wrong.